# Почему не работает с шаблонами функций?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Вот так все работает.

[код](http://pastebin.com/pqGGbwu9)

Но когда я раскомментирую

```
template < class T >
```

поставлю в параметре функции T *arr вместо int *arr, то выбивает такие [ошибки](http://pastebin.com/K6AUmqyS)

В чем проблема и куда копать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал, ну я и леньтяй, документация тащит

```
std::thread threadBubbleSort( bubbleSort<int>, array, array_size );
threadBubbleSort.join();

std::thread threadSelectSort( selectSort<int>, array, array_size );
threadSelectSort.join();
```